# How to only get number of sheets which is not hidden in Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

All:

I am pretty new to Apache POI, when I parse an Excel file, I need to know the number of sheets need to be shown, but .getNumberOfSheets() only give me all sheets, I wonder how can I know which sheets have been hidden(when u right click on a sheet tab and choose "Hide") so that I can skip counting that?

Thanks

Comment: Iterate over all the sheets, and check their hidden status?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, what is the API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just loop over all the sheets, and use the [isSheetHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#isSheetHidden%28int%29) and [isSheetVeryHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#isSheetVeryHidden%28int%29) methods to check, eg

```
int hidden = 0;
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"));
for (int sn=0; sn<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sn++) {
   if (wb.isSheetHidden(sn) || wb.isSheetVeryHidden(sn)) {
      hidden++;
   }
}
```

See the [isSheetHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#isSheetHidden%28int%29) and [isSheetVeryHidden](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#isSheetVeryHidden%28int%29) javadocs for details of what counts as hidden, and what counts as very hidden in Excel terms.

Comment: Thanks, I find out that API.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Workbook wb=  WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"));
 for (int sn=0; sn<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sn++) {
     if (wb.isSheetHidden(sn) || wb.isSheetVeryHidden(sn)) {
          // hidden sheet
     }else{
          // without hidden sheet
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, can you describe how this code works/solves the OP's problem? Code-only answers often don't serve the interests of readers as much as we would like them to.